# How to use taskset with more than 128 cores?

Tags: bash, schedule, tasksel, task-management, scheduler

I am using taskset with more than 128 cores.

I know that a cpu with less than 32 cores can run the following:

```
taskset -p 0xFFFFFFFF pid
```

How do I present the other cores besides the 32 cores.

Thanks.